# How to calculate the non-zero elements in the array?

Tags: c, arrays

How to calculate the non-zero elements in the array - without warning?
I have simple code:

```
int i;
char *symbols[1000];
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   symbols[i] = "Hi :-)";
}

i++;
symbols[i] = NULL;

int mumberofelements = 0;

for(i=0; i < 1000; i++){
   if(symbols[i] != NULL){ // WARNING comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
   numberofelemets++;
   }
}
```

But I have warning:

> comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]

How can I fix it?

Comment: are you sure it's `char *`?

Comment: Looks like he's trying to count the non-null elements of a character array without realizing that "empty" is not the same as `NULL`.

Comment: please post valid code which reproduces the problem. as it is now, it doesn't even compile.

Comment: Also note that you didn't initialize your entire array, you may get junk results.

Comment: `mumberofelements` typo. also `#inlcude <stddef.h>`

Comment: I don't believe that you've given the correct code.  The compiler should not be complaining about the code you show (or, at least, not about the bit you claim it is complaining about — it should be complaining that `numberofelemets` is an undefined variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly check against `NULL`

```
for(i=0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   if(!symbols[i])    // If pointer is NULL then increase the elements
      numberofelemets++;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, use the `NUL` (and not `NULL`) **character,** i. e. `if (symbols[i] != '\0')`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(symbols[i] != NULL) -> if(!symbols[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL is defined as a pointer type, usually (void*)0.

The problem is with the following: `symbols[i] != NULL`.

The correct way to do this is compare it to something of the same type, in this case you are looking for the null string i.e. `if(!symbols[i])`