# Is there a way to check if char * is null with bitwise

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a char array. Some of the elements allocated, and some are not.
I want to count all those not allocated without asking if `(!arr[i])`

```
char* arr[500];
.
.
.
for(i=0; i < 500; ++i)
{
   if( !arr[i] )
   { 
      counter++;
   }
}
```

but making some bitwise magic like this in C

```
for(i=0; i < 500; ++i)
{
    counter += !(arr[i]| 0x00); //this does not work 
}
```

Maybe the question is more general: is there a way to compare any pointer with NULL with bitwise operations.

Edit: no, not with `==`; I understand how to do it with `==`, but I assume when it is compiled, it does not differ from `if(!arr[i])` in assembler.

Comment: Why not just `counter += (arr[i] == NULL)`?

Comment: What "bitwise"? Why do you even... I mean, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @fasked I assume == translated into something similar to  if(!arr[i])

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the non-zero elements in the array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839793/how-to-calculate-the-non-zero-elements-in-the-array)

Comment: It seems that it's homework/finals time.

Comment: (And nobody can be bothered to do their own friggin' homework.)

Comment: Bitwise i'm asking, how to do it in bitwise,not with ==

Comment: @DavidBo It's not possible, because `NULL` is not has to be represented with all zero-bits.

Comment: Step back, think _gloves_... isn't `if (!arr[i])` easy to read? why would you want to make life more complicated than it already is?

Comment: wanted to know if it is possible after reading this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/2549281

Comment: @fasked: the null pointer *constant* is always 0-valued, hence the `NULL` macro is always going to be zero-valued (6.3.2.3/3 plus footnote 66); the corresponding null pointer *value* does not have to be zero-valued, but in the context of the source code, you're dealing with the null pointer *constant*.  Having said that, `!arr[i]` or `arr[i] == NULL` are both safer than using a bitwise operation.

Comment: @JohnBode Yes, that is what I meant. `0` integer *value* and `NULL` pointer *value* may be not equal bit by bit.

Comment: @DavidBo In your "this does not work loop", you might need to explain how it doesn't work. Since `x | 0 == x`, your `arr[i] | 0x00 == arr[i]`, so the code is no different than `counter += !(arr[i])`...

Comment: @twalberg compiler does not allow to make bitwise OR between pointer and 0. it gives error : invalid operands to binary | (have ‘char *’ and ‘int’). So i wondered if there still some syntax that allows it.

Comment: @DavidBo Ah, right... There is specific syntax to force it to work (hint: casts), but, as I mentioned, because `x | 0 == x` always, there's not really any point in it. The compiler would likely generate nearly identical code to your working example, even if you did force it - it would likely know that there's no point to OR with a constant 0, and so would optimize it away...

Comment: @twalberg it actually did work, thanks for your hint.
   for(i=0; i < 500; i++)
   {
    counptr += !( (int)arr[i] | 0x0 );
    printf("%d\n",counptr);
   }

Comment: Dabo, please explain how reading the branch prediction question made you think that bitwise operations are superior?

Comment: @Leeor not superior, but in the answer to the linked question presented bitwise technique reduced execution time, because  `if` was eliminated from the loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(i=0; i < 500; ++i)
{
    counter += arr[i] == NULL;
}
```

Or even...

```
for(i=0; i < 500; ++i)
{
    counter += !arr[i];
}
```

Comment: I suspect that casting to `bool` is not portable to systems with non-zero NULL pointers.

Comment: @user694733 However, `!arr[i]` is always true if `arr[i]` is a `NULL` pointer, regardless to the actual numeric value of the null pointer.